# SCORM - How to update Lesson status using internal menu/quick link to next SCO in SCORM?

Tags: scorm

I have developed a course in HTML and I have created the menu and linked to respective html page in imsmanifest.xml the issue is if user navigate to next lesson using internal link the status is not updating in LMS e.g.  SCO.html  has internal link to SCO2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you have all your content pages call a javascript function to update lesson_location? That way when the new HTML page loads it will update the location. That's probably the easiest way, though not the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

In SCORM, you should not be directly linking from one SCO to another SCO. The LMS is responsible for navigation between SCOs. This is because, in SCORM, a SCO should be reusable in other courses that may not contain the other SCO you are linking to.

If you are using SCORM 2004, you can use an adl.nav request to request that the user be navigated to a certain SCO. If you are using SCORM 1.2, then you should either combine all of your existing SCOs into one big SCO, or just let the LMS present the table of contents and handle the navigation.

To get the status to update, make sure that you are always calling LMSFinish/Terminate whenever the SCO unloads. It is good practice to include these called in the onunload and onbeforeunload events to ensure that they are always invoked.

Also, make sure that you are setting cmi.core.lesson_status/cmi.completion_status as soon as the user has achieved completion. Ideally you should not wait for the SCO to be unloading to make these calls.

([More basic information on how the SCORM Run-Time works](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/))

Simply updating the lesson location value will not automatically save your current location. You then need to retrieve this value and explicitly redirect your user back to where they left of.